# Processing certain form elements to build objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

All,

I have a section of a form where the user can add elements dynamically. They are able to add rows containing 3 input fields at a time. Note that I am not binding these dynamic elements to the model - I will handle in the HTTP POST processing controller.

[image]

Each added row represents a *Co-sponsor* object that will need to be created in the
form processing controller action for the HTTP POST and then inserted into the database.

I was wondering what is the best way to name these elements so I can easily create the objects in the processing controller?

Currently, the elements are being named like this:

```
cosponsorcontact_1
cosponsoremail_1
cosponsorphone_1

cosponsorcontact_2
cosponsoremail_2
cosponsorphone_2

cosponsorcontact_4
cosponsoremail_4
cosponsorphone_4

cosponsorcontact_n
cosponsoremail_n
cosponsorphone_n
```

This will involve a lot of regexing and looping to put these back together and thus create the objects. I am assuming that these elements may be in the Request.Form collection in a random order and that we may not have sequential numbering of the ids as shown in the example above.

I can certainly do it that way but I am sure that there has to be an easier way, perhaps in the naming convention of the form elements?

**Here is a snippet of the generated form content:**

```
<div id="cosponsors_6" style="display: block;">
    <label>Sponsor club name</label></span>
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor contact" placeholder="Name" name="cosponsorcontact_6" id="cosponsorcontact_6">
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor email" placeholder="Email" name="cosponsoremail_6" id="cosponsoremail_6">
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor phone" placeholder="Phone" name="cosponsorphone_6" id="cosponsorphone_6"><a class="icon delete"></a>
</div>
<div id="cosponsors_7" style="display: block;">
    <label>Sponsor club name</label></span>
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor contact" placeholder="Name" name="cosponsorcontact_7" id="cosponsorcontact_7">
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor email" placeholder="Email" name="cosponsoremail_7" id="cosponsoremail_7">
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor phone" placeholder="Phone" name="cosponsorphone_7" id="cosponsorphone_7"><a class="icon delete"></a><
</div>
<div id="cosponsors_8" style="display: block;">
    <label>Sponsor club name</label></span>
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor contact" placeholder="Name" name="cosponsorcontact_8" id="cosponsorcontact_8">
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor email" placeholder="Email" name="cosponsoremail_8" id="cosponsoremail_8">
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor phone" placeholder="Phone" name="cosponsorphone_8" id="cosponsorphone_8"><a class="icon delete"></a>
</div>
<div id="cosponsors_9" style="display: block;">
    <label>Sponsor club name</label></span>
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor contact" placeholder="Name" name="cosponsorcontact_9" id="cosponsorcontact_9">
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor email" placeholder="Email" name="cosponsoremail_9" id="cosponsoremail_9">
    <input type="text" title="Co-sponsor phone" placeholder="Phone" name="cosponsorphone_9" id="cosponsorphone_9"><a class="icon delete"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Phil Haack's article on model binding to a list](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) covers posting back non-sequential list items.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cosponsorContacts.Index" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="cosponsorContacts[3].contact" value="Whatever" />
<input type="text" name="cosponsorContacts[3].email" value="Here" />
<input type="text" name="cosponsorContacts[3].phone" value="Digits" />

<input type="hidden" name="cosponsorContacts.Index" value="7" />
<input type="text" name="cosponsorContacts[7].contact" value="One" />
<input type="text" name="cosponsorContacts[7].email" value="Two" />
<input type="text" name="cosponsorContacts[7].phone" value="Three/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update...**

My answer here wasn't quite right for the problem, but for the sake of future readers, I thought I should reference this [clean, concise solution](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) that can be easily extended for dynamically adding editor template views with AJAX.

**Original post...**

Assuming that you're trying to get those elements to bind to an `ICollection` property inside some view model that your action is expecting, then the naming convention at the input fields would look like:

```
id="ViewModelProperty_0__ObjectProperty" name="ViewModelProperty[0].ObjectProperty"
id="ViewModelProperty_1__ObjectProperty" name="ViewModelProperty[1].ObjectProperty"
id="ViewModelProperty_n__ObjectProperty" name="ViewModelProperty[n].ObjectProperty"
```

In other words, trying to use your example, if your action looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(SponsorsEditViewModel postData) { ...
```

And your classes look like:

```
public class SponsorViewModel { 
    public String CoSponsorName { get; set; }
    public String CosponserEmail { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class SponsorsEditViewModel {
    public ICollection<SponsorViewModel> Sponsors { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then your input fields should end up naming as follows:

```
<input id="Sponsors_0__CoSponsorName" name="Sponsors[0].CoSponsorName" ...
<input id="Sponsors_0__CoSponsorEmail" name="Sponsors[0].CoSponsorEmail" ...

<input id="Sponsors_1__CoSponsorName" name="Sponsors[1].CoSponsorName" ...
<input id="Sponsors_1__CoSponsorEmail" name="Sponsors[1].CoSponsorEmail" ...

...

<input id="Sponsors_n__CoSponsorName" name="Sponsors[n].CoSponsorName" ...
<input id="Sponsors_n__CoSponsorEmail" name="Sponsors[n].CoSponsorEmail" ...
```

Note that we use an `ICollection` instead of an `IEnumerable` since `IEnumerable` is read-only. The bind would fail with it.

Also, I seem to remember that if the sequence is broken (i.e. a number is skipped), then anything after that skip will not bind.

Of course, MVC3 can auto-generate all of this for you, but in this case you're dynamically generating these new fields.

As a side note, take a look at [editor templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx) if you're not familiar with them already.

Hope this helps.

*Addendum for future readers... Note that my solution here would not address the handling of non-sequential numbering.*

Comment: You are right. If the sequence has gaps, not all will be bound and I am certain that there will be cases where this occurs. That's why I did not go this route.

Comment: Ah! I somehow missed that you're specifically looking to handle non-sequential numbering. Need more coffee.