# Generating a list of RadioButtons with the same name in a for-loop in an ASP.NET MVC3 view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, for-loop, radio-button

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC3 project, and I have a problem with RadioButtons name generated by a `for` loop in a PartialView.
First, here is my code, I'll explain the exact problem just after :

**Model FileUploadModel**

```
public class FileUploadModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

    public bool IsMainFile { get; set; }
}
```

**Model MyModel**

```
public class MyModel
{
    // Some properties

    public List<FileUploadModel> Files { get; set; }
}
```

**How the PartialView _UploadFiles is called**

```
@Html.Partial("_UploadFiles", Model) // Model is a MyModel model
```

**PartialView _UploadFiles** - HERE IS THE PROBLEM

```
@model MyModel

@{
    var nbFiles = (Model.Files != null ? Model.Files.Count : 0);
    const int NB_DEFAULT_UPLOAD_FIELDS = 3;
}

@for (int i = 0; i < NB_DEFAULT_UPLOAD_FIELDS; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files[nbFiles].File, new { type = "file", name = "Files", id = "Files" })
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Files[nbFiles].IsMainFile, "Main ?", new { id = "rb" + i + "_File_IsMain" })
}
```

So this is the last snippet the problem. I'd like to create 3 upload fields with an associated RadioButton indicating if the file is the "main file". However, with the above snippet, the displayed view is OK, but when I validate my form, my posted model only have the first picture uploaded (and the corresponding boolean `IsMainFile` , the others are just ignored). That means the List `Files` contains only the first TextBox and first RadioButton data

So I tried with `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Files[i].IsMainFile`, but the RadioButtons have a different name so user can check all RadioButtons, which is NOT the desired behavior. MVC doesn't authorize me to override the `name` of the RadioButtons, so I can't give them my own name.

How can I generate these fields is order to only ONE Radiobutton can be checked AND my `MyModel.Files` property contains all chosen files ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet here is to use [editor templates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/672591/Exploring-Display-and-Editor-Templates-in-ASP-NET).

First, you create a view named `FileUploadModel`, and place it a folder named `EditorTemplates` which should exist under your controller's `Views` folder. Note that the name of the view must match the name of your view model's class.

Its contents would look something like:

```
@model FileUploadModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsMainFile, true)
```

Then, back in your `"_UploadFiles"` view, your markup for the input field and radio button would change to:

```
@model MyModel

using (Html.BeginForm(...

    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Files)

...
```

Note that this will automatically iterate through and apply that editor template for each `FileUploadModel` object, and automatically name them as required. This of course assumes that the `Files` property in your model is populated.

Your action that accepts the post should accept type `MyModel` as its sole parameter, and everything should bind up automatically at post.

There are ways to avoid editor templates and [build and name those fields programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631107/processing-certain-form-elements-to-build-objects/21631608#21631608), but this is really the preferred way, and much cleaner.

**More specific to your issue...** (In other words, I forgot that the code above won't group radio buttons.)

For the grouping of radio buttons to work, you should set the attribute name as follows:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.IsMainFile, true, new { Name = "IsMainFile" })
```

**Case matters here.** Note that `Name` must be capitalized for this to work. I'm not sure why this is the case.

**The problem is that once you change that attribute, this field will no longer automatically bind in the post.** This is unfortunate but understandably is as designed since, if you look at the request, I believe you will see that only the selected radio button value has been posted.

So, you could change the value of the radio button to something recognizable since just that one instance of `IsMainFile` will show up in the request, if I'm correct.

Perhaps you can use this specific knowledge to tweak your existing code.

Comment: Whoops, this isn't handling the radio button grouping as I expected it too.  I will update my answer shortly...

Comment: I didn't know about Editor Templates (newbie here), but I guess I will love it. However, 2 questions : First, I don't have any EditorTemplate folder, and I'm not sure where I have to create it... In my Views folder ?
Then, in my partial view, how do MVC replaces my `EditorFor` by the content of the `FileUploadModel.cshtml` (this is the appropriate name, isn't it ?) Is there any `@using` to use ?

Comment: @user2687153 Yes, you can go ahead and create the `EditorTemplates` folder. It should be created under the controller's respective views folder (`Views\%ControllerName%\EditorTemplates`).  No `@using` necessary. This functionality is all part of the framework. When you use the `EditorFor` helper, it looks for an editor template of the *same name* as the model's type that is being passed in. This is why the editor template file must be named the same (in your case, `FileUploadModel.cshtml`).

Comment: By the way, my answer above still does not address the issue you're having with grouping the radio buttons. My memory failed me and I forgot that this is not automatic. I'll try to add that to this answer shortly.

Comment: Ok, I think I have understood BUT... As you can see in my first post, my partial view is call with an `MyModel` model. So, my partial view begins with @model MyModel`. However, the template you suggest me accepts a `FileUploadModel`, so if I undestood, MVC can't match, and indeed, nothing is displayed (no error in console).
Have I to remove partial view and call the editor template from my master view ? If yes, how can I do that ?

Comment: @user2687153 You are creating a new view that is completely separate from the `MyModel` view. So you will end up having `Views\%ControllerName%\_UploadFiles.cshtml` and `Views\%ControllerName%\EditorTemplates\FileUploadModel.cshtml`. Does that make sense? I link to an article about editor templates in my answer. Check it out for much more detail.

Comment: Ok this is now perfectly working, thank you for your time (and your last update, I used `name` and not `Name`) and for showing me `EditorTemplates`, I will deeply look at this (and try not to use them everywhere because it seems really great !) Thanks again :-)